# Error en aplicación Excel VBA y Visual FoxPro

Tags: excel, vba, visual-foxpro

Hice una aplicación que usa VBA en Excel 2013 que lee datos de Excel y los guarda en tablas de Visual FoxPro. Esta aplicación corre perfectamente en cierto computador, pero al pasarlo a otro aparece este mensaje:

> "Error 3706: No se encontró el proveedor especificado. Es posible que
>   no esté instalado correctamente."

A dicho computador se le instaló (y se le volvió a instalar) el VFP OLE DB Provider (de VFP 9 SP 2) y el runtime de Visual FoxPro 9 SP2, pero el error persiste. Cuál puede ser la causa del problema y su solución?

Los equipos en los que corren los programas de Excel tienen Windows 7 Professional con SP1 64 bits y Office 2013 Professional de 32 bits.

Comment: Me parece que lo lógico es que si tienes el sistema operativo de 64 bits instales las aplicaciones de 64 bits. Algunos me han dicho, que son mejor las 32 bits pero no han sabido explicar por qué. Si tienes alguna explicación de tu caso particular, sería bueno que la agregaras. Por otro lado, cuando dices "lee datos de Excel" es ambiguo ¿Cuál es el formato de los archivos? ¿Se realiza la lectura con con los archivos abiertos por el usuario o por el VBA? Trata de reproducir el problema con el menor número de líneas de código posible y agrega este código a la pregunta. Referencia [mcve].

Comment: @Rubén Por problemas de compatibilidad con otras aplicaciones, se decidió usar Excel de 32 bits en máquinas de 64 bits. (Incluso, Microsoft pide usar versiones de 32 bits de sus librerías de manejo de datos en plataformas de 64 bits.) Por otro lado, la aplicación toma datos de varias hojas de un libro de Excel, leyéndolas celda por celda y  los pasa a tablas de Visual FoxPro, usando macros escritas en VBA.

Comment: Agrega los detalles que compartes en el comentario a la pregunta.